# A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. after running an old project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I am trying to run an old project on Android Studio, it used to work fine but now trying to run again without making any changes. I have tried many things but had no success and getting this error. Any help will be appreciated

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

I've updated the Gradle version but not sure where it's failing now.

Here is the gravel file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.name"
        minSdkVersion 30
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

     //implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:0.8.2'
    //implementation 'com.beust:klaxon:0.30'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this project can run normally in the past, generally only need `File -> Invalidate Caches`

Comment: Yeah tried that multiple times but didn't work